# Notification icon suddenly isn't shown in the right size

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a very simple application on Google Play called "Drinkly". Before reading further, please check app's screenshots on [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.matejhacin.stayhydrated&hl=en).

You can see that the notification icon is perfectly displayed on both screenshots.

And now suddenly this is how it's displayed:
[image]

And I have no idea why. I don't know what I changed, what I screwed up to make it this way. And I have no idea how to fix is so it can be displayed normally again.

I've been simply using ic_launcher icon to display it all the time like this:

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
```

and it always worked and displayed the icon perfectly. But now suddenly it doesn't work anymore. I have no idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem by seperately setting small and large icon.

```
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.smallicon)
.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher))
```